# Using <image> svg tag with React

Tags: svg, reactjs

I wish to use the svg `<image>` tag with React, but it is not supported at the moment.

Is there any workaround other than inserting html dangerously?

Will it be supported in the near future?

What is the reason this particular svg tag is not supported?

Thanks

Comment: Only the developer(s) of React could answer the last two questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is no other workaround other than `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`
- You should watch [Issue #1657](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1657) as they will probably announce it there when it's ready

Answer (score 0):

It is now supported just use:

```
<svg>
  <image xlinkHref="//url.of.image" width={600} height={400} />
</svg>
```